# ZF2 route to controller

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I have created a controller called "ActividadesPlanificadasController.php" and I have defined in my module.config the next routing but it is not work.

```
'publico/peticiones-incidencias-planificadas/actividades-planificadas' => array(
    'type'    => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => 'publico/peticiones-incidencias-planificadas/actividades-planificadas',
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Privado\Controller',
            'controller'    => 'Index',
            'action'        => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                //'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action][/:id/:system]]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'            => '[0-9]*',
                    'system'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                    //'system'  => '[0-9]*'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

These are my controllers ...

```
    'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Publico\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class,
        'Publico\Controller\Login' => Controller\LoginController::class,
        'Publico\Controller\NoAccess' => Controller\NoAccessController::class,
        'Publico\Controller\ActividadesPlanificadas'    =>  Controller\ActividadesPlanificadasController::class
    ),
),
```

Because I want to access to my controller with the next url: http://gnsys.local/publico/peticiones-incidencias-planificadas/actividades-planificadas

And I've got the next error ...

> A 404 error occurred
>   Page not found.
>
> The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.
>
> Controller:
>       Publico\Controller\PeticionesIncidenciasPlanificadas(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Publico\Controller\PeticionesIncidenciasPlanificadas)
>
> No Exception available

What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1:

I have updated my module.config and it works with the route: http://gnsys.local/publico/actividades-planificadas

module.config:

```
                'publico/actividades-planificadas' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                            'route'    => 'publico/actividades-planificadas',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Publico\Controller',
                                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                                    'action'        => 'index',
                            ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => true,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                            'default' => array(
                                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            //'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action][/:id/:system]]',
                                            'constraints' => array(
                                                    'controller'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                    'action'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                                    'id'            => '[0-9]*',
                                                    'system'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                                                    //'system'  => '[0-9]*'
                                            ),
                                            'defaults' => array(
                                            ),
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            ),

    'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Publico\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class,
        'Publico\Controller\Login' => Controller\LoginController::class,
        'Publico\Controller\NoAccess' => Controller\NoAccessController::class,
        'Publico\Controller\ActividadesPlanificadas'    =>  Controller\ActividadesPlanificadasController::class
    ),
),
```

But I want that my route to access to ActividadesPlanificadasController would be: http://gnsys.local/publico/peticiones-incidencias-actividades/actividades-planificadas

If I change my module.config to ...

```
'publico/peticiones-incidencias-planificadas/actividades-planificadas' => array(
'type'    => 'Literal',
'options' => array(
    'route'    => 'publico/peticiones-incidencias-planificadas/actividades-planificadas',
    'defaults' => array(
        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Publico\Controller',
        'controller'    => 'Index',
        'action'        => 'index',
    ),
),
'may_terminate' => true,
'child_routes' => array(
    'default' => array(
        'type'    => 'Segment',
        'options' => array(
            //'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action][/:id/:system]]',
            'constraints' => array(
                'controller'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                'action'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                'id'            => '[0-9]*',
                'system'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                //'system'  => '[0-9]*'
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
),
```

I've got the error

> ```
> A 404 error occurred Page not found.
>
> The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.
>
> Controller: Publico\Controller\PeticionesIncidenciasPlanificadas(resolves to
> ```
>
> invalid controller class or alias:
>   Publico\Controller\PeticionesIncidenciasPlanificadas)
>
> ```
> No Exception available
> ```

What am I still doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You point to a controller called `'Privado\Controller\Index'` but your invokable is called `'Publico\Controller\Index'`.

Change the `namespace` so it corresponds.

```
Privado -> Publico
```

or

```
Publico -> Privado
```

or add a controller for `'Privado\Controller\Index'`

```
'invokables' => array(
    'Privado\Controller\Index' => //your privado controller,
    //...other controllers...
)
```

### UPDATE

Make also sure you have an invokable controller class in the correct namespace. So if you register like this:

```
'invokables' => array(
    'Privado\Controller\Index' => 'Privado\Controller\IndexController'
)
```

You need a controller class in a php file called `IndexController.php` in the folder `Privado` - `Controller`

```
- Privado
  - Controller
    - IndexController.php
```

And the class should have the correct name and namespace constant:

```
<?php
namespace = Privado\Controller;

class IndexController extends ... {

}
```

Comment: @JoséCarlos I added an update. This is basic ZF2 stuff, maybe you should consider doing some reading in the ZF2 tuturials, it might help you to understand your ZF2 configuration.